# How to make a interface extend ActionBarActivity

Tags: java, android, interface

I am making a app that requires a lot of coding, so i want to make it organized. This was done in the past by extending multiple classes until and adding ActionBarActivity at the end, however that can get complicated. I heard about interfaces and want to try it out. How can i create a method in my interface that i can just call from anywhere in the code. when i create a interface and extend ActionBarActivity it gives me an error saying "interface expected here".

```
public interface buttonClick extends ActionBarActivity  {
// i want to be able to do the to do code here for the app
```

}

```
public class scoutingFragment extends Fragment {
public static scoutingFragment newInstance()
{
    scoutingFragment fragment = new scoutingFragment();
    return fragment;
}
public scoutingFragment()
{

}
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container , Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.scouting,container,false);
    return rootView;
}
public void onAttach(Activity activity){
    super.onAttach(activity);
    ((MainActivity)activity).onSectionAttached(0);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "call from anywhere in my code?"  Please note that an interface is a contract with a class. When you implement it you must provide an implementation for any methods defined within the interface.  Read up on http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html

Comment: How can i organize my code using interfaces. And by calling it from anywhere i meant i want to be able to call it from a fragment.

Comment: How can we help you organize your code when we haven't seen your code?

Answer (score 0):

Interface can just extend another interface. It cannot extend an abstract or concrete class.

```
public interface MySuperInterface {
}

public interface MyInterface extends MySuperInterface {
}
```

But using interfaces in this case won't make your code easier to maintain. Try to remodel your classes separating their responsibilities and always prefer composition over inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Java interfaces do not extends classes they extends only interfaces which make sense because classes have implementation while interfaces have only declaration.

In your scenario if you extends ActionBarActivity you have to give implentation of its abstract function and obviously you can not give implementation in an interface.thats why it is not allowing you to extends a class